# Why does select always choose default?

Tags: go, channel

I worte some code to run ffmpeg, to have full control of it, I use pipe to handle its input and output, the input and output code snippets are as shown below:

```
    done = make(chan interface{})
    keyFrame = make(chan struct{})
    cmdStr := fmt.Sprintf("ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f mjpeg -r 20 -i pipe:0 -vf scale=600:-2 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -profile:v baseline -preset medium -r 20 -f h264 -", udid)
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(context.Background(), "bash", "-c", cmdStr)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    //prepare stdin
    stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    imgReader, err := GetMJpegReader(URL, imgHandler, done)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("unable to create image reader")
        return
    }
    mjpegStream := imgReader.GetMjpegStream()
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Println("input Done()")
                return
            case <-keyFrame:
                stdin.Write(blank)
            default:
                img := <-mjpegStream
                if _, err := stdin.Write(img); err != nil {
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
    }(ctx)

    //prepare stdout
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    imgCh = make(chan []byte)
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        var lastByte []byte
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Println("output Done()")
                if cmd.Process != nil {
                    cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGKILL)
                    log.Println("exit status", cmd.ProcessState)
                }
                return
            default:
                payload := make([]byte, 100000)
                length, err := stdout.Read(payload)
                if err != nil {
                    break
                }
                if reflect.DeepEqual(payload[:4], []byte{0, 0, 0, 1}) {
                    imgCh <- lastByte
                    lastByte = payload[:length]
                } else {
                    lastByte = append(lastByte, payload[:length]...)
                }
            }
        }
    }(ctx)

    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        close(done)
        cancel()
    }

    go func() {
        select {
        case <-done:
            cancel()
        }
    }()
```

but when I invoke `cancel`, only the `<-ctx.Done()` case in the input goroutine can be executed. While in the output goroutine, select will always go into default case, which makes the output run indefinitely even if ffmpeg itself was stoped. Why is this happening? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @EmilePels Edited, but I don't know how to provide a workable mjpeg server

Comment: A [mre] would not include the mjpeg server, it would replicate the minimal logic require to reproduce your question, which has to do with select behavior. The short answer is this is how select works, `default` is always taken when no other cases can proceed.

Comment: "Start starts the specified command _but does not wait for it to complete_." It is always an error to call Start but not [Wait](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Wait). Cancel the context after Wait returns. The done channel is superfluous. You may have to close the stdin pipe to make ffmpeg exit. Also, run `go vet`; the Sprintf call is invalid.

Comment: @Peter your reply really helps. I am wondering if there is a way to gracefully close the stdin and stdout instead of let them encounter an error?

Comment: The Close method *is* graceful. Wait will close stdout, so you don't have to (and shouldn't) do that yourself. Only stdin has to be closed to let ffmpeg exit (I think).

Comment: @Peter I start the ffmpeg on demand, and close it after finishing, as I know, Wait waits for the process to stop by itself